# Issue with MVCMailer

Tags: mvcmailer

Not sure if anyone else has run into this issue but I'm trying to send emails using MVCMailer. I was able to get it installed and updated the T4Scaffolding package without any issues.

I have an aspx page that is creating a report and I want that report attached to the email. However, when I turn around and call my SendReport method in the UserMailers class it throws an error on the PopulateBody call saying that routeData is null

Here is my code

```
public class UserMailer : MailerBase, IUserMailer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Email Reports using this method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toAddress">The address to send to.</param>
    /// <param name="viewName">The name of the view.</param>
    /// <returns>The mail message</returns>
    public MailMessage SendReport(string toAddress, string viewName)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage { Subject = "Report Mail" };
        message.To.Add(toAddress);

        ViewBag.Name = "Testing-123";

        this.PopulateBody(mailMessage: message, viewName: "SendReport");

        return message;
    }
}
```

The error I get is "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: routeData"

I've looked online and haven't found anything that is related to this issue or anyone who has run into this problem.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue but oddly only for one or two of the emails we're sending, did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Hi @George, Did you find any solution for this issue, I am facing the same issue, even though I am using MVC controller

Answer (score 2):

It is called **Mvc** Mailer for a reason.
You can't use it in a normal asp.net (.aspx) project, only in a MVC project.

Comment: Filip - Please point out where in my post it states that the project isn't an MVC project? There are numerous examples of people using web forms within an MVC project.

Comment: my bad, i assumed wrong :) Still, the issue remains, the routes aren't loaded if you call a .aspx webform.

Answer (score 0):

As Filip said it cannot be used within codebehind in an ASP.NET ASPX page because there is no `ControllerContext` / `RequestContext`.

The easiest way for me was to just create a controller action and then use `WebClient` to make an http request from the ASPX page.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        var sendEmailUrl = "https://" + Request.Url.Host + 
                           Page.ResolveUrl("~/email/SendGenericEmail") + 
                           "?emailAddress=email@example.com" + "&template=Template1";

        wc.DownloadData(sendEmailUrl);
    }
```

Then I have a simple controller

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SendGenericEmail(string emailAddress, string template)
    {
        // send email
        GenericMailer mailer = new GenericMailer();

        switch (template)
        {
            case "Template1":

                var email = mailer.GenericEmail(emailAddress, "Email Subject");
                email.Send(mailer.SmtpClient);
                break;

            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("Template " + template + " not handled");
        }

        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        };
    }
}
```

Of course there are many issues, such as security, protocol (the controller won't have access to the original page), error handling - but if you find yourself stuck this can work.